# Python - sql query adds \r to string ? How to remove it?

Tags: python, sql, string, ms-access

I am working on a script that queries a MS access file and stores the results in dataframe. However, the result of the query look like this -

```
conn_str = (r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\User1\Documents\Freight\Database2.accdb;')
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
query = pd.read_sql_query('''select
Port,
Charges,
Reference, 
Forwarder,
Carrier from List''',cnxn)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(query, columns = 
['Port','Charges','Forwarder','Reference', 'Carrier'])
 df1.head(1)
 Output:
  Port  Charges      Reference   Forwarder Carrier
ABC          10    \r7UH3924       XYZ      PQR
```

If you look at the results returned for the reference column - an unwanted /r is added there. Why is it there? How to remove it?

The desired result is simply - 7UH3924

Answer (score 0):

u can use `x.strip()`, example as below:

```
a = "\r7UH3924"
b = a.strip()
```

output:

```
b="7UH3924"
```

Comment: This does not explain why the extra \r is added there. Also note that I'm trying to avoid the \r from appearing, I do not want to just remove it from a string

Comment: Yes, please look at the edited post. I have included the code now.

Comment: I don't know where u get the db data, but it should be better if u share the code of how u 
 or someone else INSERT the data.